# preg_replace issue with html elements

Tags: php, preg-match

i'm having issues with my preg_match solution.

I have the following html code:

```
<h1> Text marking test</h1><b> Chicago</b> - This is the    text. Can this problem be solved by you?
```

I also have almost similar content:
Chicago - This is the text. Can this issue be solved by you?
All multiple spaces are gone and **Problem** has turned into **Issue**

I want to mark:

1. Chicago - This is the    text. Can this
2. be solved by you?

So i get this:

```
<h1> Text marking test</h1><div class="marked"><b> Chicago</b> - This is the    text. Can this</div> problem <div class="marked">be solved by you?</div>
```

I have the following regular expression pattern which works:

```
$string = preg_replace( "/(?im)(<b>)*Chicago([\s,.!?:;'\"]|<([^>]+)>)*-([\s,.!?:;'\"]|<([^>]+)>)*This([\s,.!?:;'\"]|<([^>]+)>)*is([\s,.!?:;'\"]|<([^>]+)>)*the([\s,.!?:;'\"]|<([^>]+)>)*text([\s,.!?:;'\"]|<([^>]+)>)*Can([\s,.!?:;'\"]|<([^>]+)>)*this([\s,.!?:;'\"]|<([^>]+)>)*/", '<div class="marked">' .'${0}'.'</div> , $string);
```

The problem is that the appending `<b>` tag could be any tag with any attribute and also optional.
It can only be the appending tag and not any tag before Chicago.
But somehow i constantly fail in my attempts. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I had misread your question and deleted my answer, but upon reading it again I think it might offer you some pointers on how to proceed. I don't completely understand the question, so please pardon the unsatisfactory answer.

---

You want to strip the text of HTML tags, as well as of multiple spaces. I would tackle these things separately:

```
function clean_text($text) {
    $text = strip_tags($text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $text);
    return $text;
}
```

Use built-in functions where possible – no sense in re-inventing the wheel, especially as usually a lot of thought went into the functions. As for the second part, we match two or more whitespace characters and replace them with one space only.

Comment: Hi Ljacqu,i don't want to strip the HTML tags. But i want to include them INSIDE the <div class="mark"> ** MY MATCHING TEXT INCLUDING THE HTML TAGS WRAPPED AROUND IT </div>

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can remove all the html tags before the text analysis by using "<[^>]*>" with replace_all, and then make a simpler text analysis regex.
I invite you to use multiple regex instead of making a big one, it's more confortable to locate a bug or update your program